# Backbonejs, changing events on View upon a (resize) event call without reloading or re-rendering page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, event-handling

I want to change/modify the event listeners on a View module when an event (resize) is called. This purpose is for functionalities concerning resizing a browser and getting a mobile view of a website and NOT having the page refresh. On resize, if a breakpoint is detected, I want to add an event. Can I do something like this?

```
eventOptions = { "click .item" : "onExpand", "click .panel" : "onPanelExpand"};

module.exports = View.extend({
     className: 'results',
     events: eventOptions,
     initialize: function (options) {
        $(window).on('resize', _.bind(this.onResize, this));
     },

     ....
     ....
     onResize: function() {
        // add to this.events
        this.events.add({"click .button": "onClickButton"});
        // refresh events without reloading page
     }

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't you just always have the button handler, but show it only when it reaches specific resolutions based on media queries?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [backbone.js source code](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js), it has two functions:

1. [delegateEvents()](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) - re-binds `this.events` or passed events to their handlers
2. delegate() - adds a single event listener to the view's element

You may use either of the two:

```
onResize: function() {
    this.events.add({"click .button": "onClickButton"});
    this.delegateEvents();
}
```

OR

```
onResize: function() {
    this.delegate("click", ".button", onClickButton);
    // Note: this will not update this.events map and you might need to undelegate to remove
}
```

However, a cleaner approach would have been to keep this event always as part of the original event map and inside event handler function, you may decide if you want to execute or skip.

Comment: I'm getting that 'add' is not a function for this.events